# How might I select specific data in an entry to be displayed when selecting an entry?

Tags: plugins, entries-field

I am not sure if i need a plugin to accomplish a specific task or if Craft CMS can natively handle this task.

I created bios for people in a channel of bios. Each entry has a Job Title text field to store a single job title.

So, I want to store a list or array of multiple job titles for each person/entry. Then, I want to choose which job title is rendered when I use the entries field to select a bio to render.

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: I'm pretty certain you _don't_ need a plugin to do what you want. However, it's a bit unclear as to what exactly you're trying to achieve (or what your architecture actually looks like).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably a dozen different ways to tackle this, but I'd probably use Craft's flexible [relationship](https://craftcms.com/docs/relations) engine by creating a `Bios` channel and a `Jobs` channel.

The `Bios` channel would have an [entries field](https://craftcms.com/docs/entries-fields) assigned to its field layout with its source set to `Jobs` and it would allow for multiple selections.

Then, when creating a new `Bios` entry, you'd select the `Job`(s) for that person.

You could pull them out into the front-end however you'd like at that point.